# Extracting the docstring from a function

Tags: clojure

How do you write a function to extract a docstring from a function?

I have been able to make the following work in a repl:

```clj
(:doc (meta (var identity)))

user=> "Returns its argument."
```

But when I wrap this in a function such as below:

```clj
(defn get-doc-string [f]
  (:doc (meta (var f))))
```

The compiler says the following:

> Unable to resolve var: f in this context

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Is this some kind of exercise?  There is already `doc` that does this.

Comment: Yes, it is an exercise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to quote, or better, syntax quote the symbol and use find-var:

```
(defn get-doc-string [f]
  (:doc (meta (find-var f))))
```

Then you can do:

```
(get-doc-string `identity)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.

Is there a way to wrap this in a function that will add the backquote so that the user just has to put in the function. I tried using `eval` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

`var` is a special form which takes a symbol argument - you are passing `f` which cannot be resolved. You can create a macro:

```
(defmacro get-doc-string [sym]
  `(:doc (meta (var ~sym))))
```

although clojure already implements this functionality in `clojure.repl/doc`.